# How to REALLY close Web worker so the browser gives back the occupied memory?

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, web-worker

What I'm planning to do is the following:
1. Start a Worker.
2a. This worker must load some huge data (via AJAX or `importScripts`), do something with it and get the result which will be stored in a variable in this worker.
2b. Load new portion of data (which must replace the previous portion), do something with it and append the desired result to the variable.
2c. ...and so on.
3. The memory usage will grow, so I must be able to force the browser to close this worker and "forget" about it. I will lose all my data, but get rid of a memory loss.
4. I will start this worker again, when I want.

I've made this test in portable Chrome-based browser (with `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag enabled, otherwise Worker won't start):

**app.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>       
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#click').on("click", function () {
            var w = new Worker('worker.js');
            w.onmessage = function (event) {
            console.log(event.data);
            };
            w.postMessage({
                "url": "hugedata1.js"
            });
            $('#click2').on("click", function () {
                w.postMessage({
                    "url": "hugedata2.js"
                });
            });
            $('#terminate').on("click", function () {
                w.terminate();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="click">start worker</div>
<div id="click2">load second portion of data</div>
<div id="terminate">terminate worker</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**worker.js:**

```
var hugedataarr;
var myarr = [];
self.onmessage = function(event) {
    importScripts(event.data.url);
    myarr[myarr.length] = hugedataarr[0];
    self.postMessage(myarr);
}
```

**hugedata.js:**

```
hugedataarr = [
{ "id": "1", "A": "b"}, 
//imagine millions of objects placed in here
{ "id": "5000000", "F": "g"}
]
```

**hugedata2.js:**

```
hugedataarr = [
{ "id": "5000001", "H": "i"}, 
//imagine millions of objects placed in here
{ "id": "10000000", "X": "y"}
]
```

Make sure that **hugedata** files are huge enough so the memory loss will be visible immediately.

Steps: 1) open "app.html" 2) click "start worker", wait, check console log 3) click "load second portion of data", wait, check console log 4) click "terminate worker" or refresh the page 5) check the memory loss 6) repeat steps 2-4 to increase the memory loss.

Question: how do I **really** close this worker, so it gives back its memory? Or, if it's not possible, how to **really** refresh the application page so the browser "forgets" about that worker once and for all and releases occupied memory? (because pressing F5 to refresh the page won't do anything to solve the memory problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scripts themselves are run and then discarded; it's only the structures and functions they define that remain. In your case, all the scripts do is create arrays and assign them to the variable `hugedataarr`. All you have to do to make the memory consumed by one of those huge arrays available for garbage collection is this (in your worker):

```
hugedataarr = undefined;
```

(Or `= []` if you want it to always refer to an array, or `= /* anything else here */`.)

Since there is no further outstanding reference to the huge array, the engine can GC it. Whether and when it does that is up to the engine.

Comment: But why web-worker-termination is not forcing the browser to **forget** about it and its data absolutely, and to free its memory **immediately**??? In reality, I can't rely on GC: when the memory consumption reaches its limit, the browser will freeze, but GC isn't doing its job, whether I do something like `hugedataarr = null`, `hugedataarr = undefined`, whatever... I just want to **refresh** the page absolutely so the UA thinks it opens it for the first time, or close Web worker and all its data completely so the UA's memory usage is at the same level as it was **before** the worker started!

Comment: @lyricallywicked: If you're using any decent engine, GC will do its job; and short of refreshing the page as a whole, you have no choice but to rely on it. It sounds like you're doing *something* to keep references to the huge arrays, preventing GC.

Comment: I'll clarify. I'm not even concerned about GC, I'm concerned about the questions that I asked in my comment above: is it possible to refresh the page to the point at which the browser's memory usage is at the same level as it was when I opened this page **for the first time**??? Neither pressing F5 (simple location reload) nor `worker.terminate()` helps.

Comment: @lyricallywicked: No, it's up to the browser to manage its memory pool. If you're doing F5, you're refeshing the page, and all of the data associated with the previous copy of that page is available for reclamation/reuse by the browser; it's not a JavaScript question anymore. When and how the browser reuses that memory, or releases it back to the OS, depends entirely on the browser's implementation. I believe Chrome's ~process-per-window model makes it happen immediately on Chrome; but the last time I looked at Firefox in this regard, it was more complicated about it.

Comment: and what about `worker.terminate()`? Why isn't this returning the memory usage to the state as it was **before** the worker started? Is this implementation-dependent, or what?

Comment: @lyricallywicked: If you're talking about F5 not releasing it, again, this has nothing whatsoever to do with the JavaScript layer, and everything to do with the browser's management of its memory.